# PyQt5: Can someone please add a menubar to this code?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am new to Python and have been trying to add a menu bar to this code for text editor. Can someone please help and add a simple menu bar with File and Edit? Doesn't matter the functionalities of those, I just want a menu bar to show up. Please help!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# QcodeEditor.py by acbetter.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QTextFormat


class QLineNumberArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__(editor)
        self.codeEditor = editor

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(self.editor.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.codeEditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class QCodeEditor(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.lineNumberArea = QLineNumberArea(self)
        self.blockCountChanged.connect(self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
        self.updateRequest.connect(self.updateLineNumberArea)
        self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.highlightCurrentLine)
        self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        digits = 1
        max_value = max(1, self.blockCount())
        while max_value >= 10:
            max_value /= 10
            digits += 1
        space = 3 + self.fontMetrics().width('9') * digits
        return space

    def updateLineNumberAreaWidth(self, _):
        self.setViewportMargins(self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0, 0, 0)

    def updateLineNumberArea(self, rect, dy):
        if dy:
            self.lineNumberArea.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            self.lineNumberArea.update(0, rect.y(), self.lineNumberArea.width(), rect.height())
        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        cr = self.contentsRect()
        self.lineNumberArea.setGeometry(QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(), self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()))

    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []
        if not self.isReadOnly():
            selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
            lineColor = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter(160)
            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)

    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.lineNumberArea)

        painter.fillRect(event.rect(), Qt.lightGray)

        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()

        # Just to make sure I use the right font
        height = self.fontMetrics().height()
        while block.isValid() and (top <= event.rect().bottom()):
            if block.isVisible() and (bottom >= event.rect().top()):
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                painter.setPen(Qt.black)
                painter.drawText(0, top, self.lineNumberArea.width(), height, Qt.AlignRight, number)

            block = block.next()
            top = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    codeEditor = QCodeEditor()
    codeEditor.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code was posted on StackOverflow by some guy. Unfortunately I cannot contact him directly nor can I write a comment on his post since I am new here. So any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most main window style applications you would use the menuBar() function provided in QMainWindow, adding QMenus to the menu bar and adding QActions to the pop-up menus.
For a description of how to create Menu Bar, see the text of the code.
Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QRect, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QTextEdit,
                             QMainWindow, QAction, qApp)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QColor, QPainter, QTextFormat, QKeySequence


class QLineNumberArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__(editor)
        self.codeEditor = editor

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(self.editor.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.codeEditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class QCodeEditor(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.lineNumberArea = QLineNumberArea(self)
        self.blockCountChanged.connect(self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
        self.updateRequest.connect(self.updateLineNumberArea)
        self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.highlightCurrentLine)
        self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        digits = 1
        max_value = max(1, self.blockCount())
        while max_value >= 10:
            max_value /= 10
            digits += 1
        space = 3 + self.fontMetrics().width('9') * digits
        return space

    def updateLineNumberAreaWidth(self, _):
        self.setViewportMargins(self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0, 0, 0)

    def updateLineNumberArea(self, rect, dy):
        if dy:
            self.lineNumberArea.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            self.lineNumberArea.update(0, rect.y(), self.lineNumberArea.width(), rect.height())
        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        cr = self.contentsRect()
        self.lineNumberArea.setGeometry(QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(), self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()))

    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []
        if not self.isReadOnly():
            selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
            lineColor = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter(160)
            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)

    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.lineNumberArea)

        painter.fillRect(event.rect(), Qt.lightGray)

        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()

        # Just to make sure I use the right font
        height = self.fontMetrics().height()
        while block.isValid() and (top <= event.rect().bottom()):
            if block.isVisible() and (bottom >= event.rect().top()):
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                painter.setPen(Qt.black)
                painter.drawText(0, top, self.lineNumberArea.width(), height, Qt.AlignRight, number)

            block = block.next()
            top = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1

#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++            
class Writer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.form_widget = QCodeEditor()            
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Create Menu Bar
        bar = self.menuBar()

        # Create Root Menus
        file = bar.addMenu('&File')
        edit = bar.addMenu('Edit')

        # Create Actions for menus
        save_action = QAction('Save', self)
        save_action.setShortcuts(QKeySequence.Save)  
        new_action  = QAction('New', self)
        new_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        quit_action = QAction('&Quit', self)
        quit_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        find_action = QAction('Find...', self)
        replace_action = QAction('Replace...', self)

        # Add actions to Menus
        file.addAction(new_action)
        file.addAction(save_action)
        file.addAction(quit_action)

        find_menu = edit.addMenu('Find')
        find_menu.addAction(find_action)
        find_menu.addAction(replace_action)

        # Events
        # triggered - This signal is emitted when an action is activated by the user; 
        # for example, when the user clicks a menu option, toolbar button, 
        # or presses an action's shortcut key combination, or when trigger() was called.  
        quit_action.triggered.connect(self.quit_trigger)
        file.triggered.connect(self.selected)

        self.setWindowTitle("My Menus")
        self.resize(600, 400)

        self.show()

    def quit_trigger(self):
        qApp.quit()

    def selected(self, q):
        print(q.text() + ' selected')




if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #codeEditor = QCodeEditor()
    #codeEditor.show()
    writer = Writer()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a saviour! I don't know why people downvoted this question. People must understand that there are beginners also. You have been a great help!